# Ansible asking for ssh key passphrase for key that does not have one

Tags: ansible, centos7

I generated an rsa_id ssh key, and used ssh-copy-id on my own account on localhost, just to test running Ansible against localhost with ssh.

I did not use a passphrase. However, when running ansible against localhost, I'm prompted with:

> Enter passphrase for key '/home/username/.ssh/id_rsa.pub':

Comment: That's because `id_rsa.pub` is **not** an SSH private key (which could conceivably have a password), it's the public key, which by definition does not have a password. I don't know why, or who, is prompting but start by pointing whatever it is at `/home/username/.ssh/id_rsa` not the `.pub` flavor and see if things get better

Comment: What is the result of `ssh localhost`? What is the contents of `ls -la ${HOME}/.ssh/`? When this command runs without a prompt, then ansible is also running without a prompt.